# Javascript + HTML with Arguments

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table with 2 rows having 2 columns each.
I want to change the innerHTML of the td when i click a td.
That is when i

```
<table border="1">
<tr id="r1">
<td id="b1_1" onclick="b(b1_1)">0</td>
<td id="b1_2" onclick="b(b1_2)">0</td>
</tr>
<tr id="r2">
<td id="b2_1" onclick="b(b2_1)">0</td>
<td id="b2_2" onclick="b(b2_2)">0</td>
</tr>
</table>


function _(x){
return document.getElementById(x);
}

function b(bid){
_x(bid).innerHTML = "5";
}
```

Comment: There is no `_x` function, as far as I can see..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`b1_1` is an identifier (for an undefined variable). You want a string literal. `'b1_1'`

Ditto for all your other arguments.

Additionally, you are trying to call a function called `_x` but have defined a function called `_`.

---

It would be neater to [use a single event listener and not use ids at all](http://jsbin.com/IXimiyE/1/) though.

```
function b(event){
    event.target.innerHTML = 5;
}

document.querySelector('table').addEventListener('click', b);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function is called incorrectly (`_x`) - You have declared it as simply `_`. So your `b` function should look like this:

```
function b(bid){
  _(bid).innerHTML = "5";
}
```

The parameters passed in the `onclick` handler would also need to be strings, hence be enclosed in quotes, i.e: `onclick="b('b1_1')"`

---

Alternatively, you could just use `this` in those `onclick` handlers:

```
<td id="b1_1" onclick="b(this)">0</td>
```

And your function would become:

```
function b(bid){
  bid.innerHTML = "5";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Alternative

Remove your `onclick` on your HTML, and, using jQuery :

```
$('tr td').click(function(){
    var previousVal = parseInt($(this).html());
    $(this).html(previousVal + 5);
});
```

It will add 5 each time you click on a div (I think this might be what you want, as you're talking about bids).